# JavaScript does not wait for file upload dialog selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code:

```
function OpenUploadFile1() {
    var myFrame = document.getElementById('frameUpload1');
    $(myFrame).focus();
    $(myFrame).contents().find("#upload_1_file").click();
    var value = $(myFrame).contents().find("#upload_1_file").val();
    if (value != '') {
        $(myFrame).contents().find("#upload_1_start").click();
    }
}
```

the line

```
var value = $(myFrame).contents().find("#upload_1_file").val();
```

gets executed without waiting for the user to select a file and close the `dialog (after the .click above)` in `FF/Chrome`, but works fine in `IE (at least IE11)`.

`frameUpload1` is an `iframe`, and `upload_1_file` is an `asp:UploadFile control`.

EDIT: for clarity, this is how the code is called:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Upload Image" onclick="OpenUploadFile1()">Upload Image</a>
<iframe id="frameUpload1" name="frameUpload1" src="fileupload.aspx" frameborder="0" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
```

Does anyone know why and how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this two may help you :

1-instead of `value != ''` use `value != null`

2-instead of `$(myFrame).contents().find("#upload_1_start")` use $("#upload_1_start")

but I'm not completely sure about second.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that if put alert('1'); right after the "var value =" line, it gets fired up while the file selection dialog is on screen. So, having "value != ''" or "value != null" probably won't help?